# Jquery - Replacing a Dom Element on load

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need to replace a following html element

```
<input type="submit" id="send_product_enquiry" value="Send Enquiry" class="button">
```

with this

```
<input type="submit" id="send_product_enquiry" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact From Enquiry', eventAction: 'Form Entry', eventLabel: 'Contact Form Enquiry'});" value="Send Enquiry" class="button">
```

I've been trying to use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#send_product_enquiry').replaceWith('<input type="submit" id="send_product_enquiry" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact From Enquiry', eventAction: 'Form Entry', eventLabel: 'Contact Form Enquiry'});" value="Send Enquiry" class="button"> ' );
});
```

but I keep getting the below error

> "Missing ) in the argument..."

I know it's a syntax thing with double or single quotes, but I just don't know what is right. Been messing around with no results.

Comment: In the snippet you have single quotes inside single quotes not being escaped so bound to generate issues. If you use quotes inside the same quotes you need to escape them with \.

Comment: @gillesc can you give me an example? Not sure what you mean "escape by `` "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add click handler with jQuery.

```
$('#send_product_enquiry').on('click', function () {
    ga('send', 'event', {
        eventCategory: 'Contact From Enquiry',
        eventAction: 'Form Entry',
        eventLabel: 'Contact Form Enquiry'
    });
});
```

Comment: Apart from the quotes I got wrong, I think this is an improved solution to what I had.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, I checked what was suggested and it seems to be working. I can work with .on('click', 'blablabla') as well. What's the downside of this? (attaching the onclick)

Comment: @NikolaL.: `onXyz` attributes create event handlers that don't play nicely with other event handlers, and mean that you have to put your code inside a string (making it easy to mess up your quotes, as in your question). Code should be *code*, not a string in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape all  your `single quotes`. See all the single quotes being escaped with **'\'**

```
 $('#send_product_enquiry').replaceWith('<input type="submit" id="send_product_enquiry" onclick="ga(\'send\', \'event\', { eventCategory: \'Contact From Enquiry\', eventAction: \'Form Entry\', eventLabel: \'Contact Form Enquiry\'});" value="Send Enquiry" class="button"> ' );
```

**WHY YOU NEED TO ESCAPE:**

While interpreting your code, you are confusing the interpreter about where  your string ends. Escaping a string means to reduce ambiguity. By preceeding with a slash, you are announcing that it is a part of a value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the string you're passing `replaceWith` ends sooner than you think it does:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#send_product_enquiry').replaceWith('<input type="submit" id="send_product_enquiry" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact From Enquiry', eventAction: 'Form Entry', eventLabel: 'Contact Form Enquiry'});" value="Send Enquiry" class="button"> ' );
 // Here -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
});
```

Any decent programming editor should have made that obvious with syntax highlighting.

To put a `'` inside a string quoted with `'`, you need to use `\'`.

---

But better yet, since you're using jQuery, hook up the handler dynamically:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var btn = $('<input type="submit" id="send_product_enquiry" value="Send Enquiry" class="button">');
  $('#send_product_enquiry').replaceWith(btn);
  btn.on("click", function() {
    ga('send', 'event', {
      eventCategory: 'Contact From Enquiry',
      eventAction: 'Form Entry',
      eventLabel: 'Contact Form Enquiry'
    });
  });
});
```

That's if you really need to *replace* the element, rather than just adding a handler to it or modifying it a bit. If all you have to do is add the handler, then:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#send_product_enquiry').on("click", function() {
    ga('send', 'event', {
      eventCategory: 'Contact From Enquiry',
      eventAction: 'Form Entry',
      eventLabel: 'Contact Form Enquiry'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Guess I'm not that decent then :). Thanks for help.

Comment: @NikolaL.: By "editor" I meant the program you use to edit code, not you.

Comment: Ah, lol, well both are true most likely. Funny how words can play tricks on you. Anyway, thanks for help. Everyday you learn something new.

Comment: @NikolaL.: I've added dynamically adding the event handler. It really should have been in my original answer.

Comment: Got it. I think I understand the pros and cons of each. And it's also much cleaner looking. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I noticed this function of yours kinda overrides the form validation. What I mean is, when you press that button it doesn't check whether fields are filled with data. Anyway I can fix that?

Comment: @NikolaL.: Not really "of mine," I just made your function work. If you want to hook into the form validation, hook the `submit` event on the form, not the `click` event on a button.